# How to display key to a file using OpenSSL?

Tags: command-line, mysql, openssl, mariadb

I'm a newbie at encryption so I could do with some help:

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on the MariaDB website to create an aes-256-cbc key to encrypt my data at rest.

The line which it tells me to copy and paste is this:

```
enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha1 -k secret -in keys.txt -out keys.enc
```

Which in this instance has returned me this.

```
Salted__›­}´3`ìe›‚Å)l‘»ŽWÝ§
```

It's not what I need.

If I use the print command it will print out the key I need. Now the key is too long to copy by hand so I need to redirect the key output to a file. Can anyone help me to put write the correct command to put the key in the file?

The key looks similar to this:

```
770A8A65DA156D24EE2A093277530142
```

EDIT: It also does not allow me to copy from the CMD prompt.

Comment: If you want the output of `-p`/`-P` to be written to a file, I suppose you can do something like `enc ... > name.txt`?

Comment: To **copy from Windows CMD prompt** (actually console window) click icon at left of titlebar (or ALT+SP) or rightclick anywhere in titlebar; choose Edit / Mark; hold mouse while dragging over the text you want OR click on one end then shiftclick on the other end; hit ENTER.

Comment: *"It also does not allow me to copy from the CMD prompt...."* - You need to enable ***Quick Edit*** mode. Also see [Command Prompt QuickEdit Mode Is Disabled by Default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/282301) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

The command you used encrypt the file `keys.txt` with a key generated from the passphrase (`secret`) you provided (and a randomly generated "salt" unless you use the `-nosalt` option as well).

I am not sure what you really want. If you want openssl to show the key generated from your passphrase / for the encryption, you can use the option `-p` (or `-P` if you don't want the actual encryption to proceed). You'll notice that the key will vary each time you run the command, unless you use `-nosalt`.

Or maybe what you want is `-base64` (although it doesn't seem to be the case according to the sample result you showed), which will further encode the encrypted file with a certain algorithm so that the output will be ASCII string: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

As you may have already noticed, if you don't want the source to be "contaminated" with a "salt header", you may also want `-nosalt` as well when you use `-base64`.

If you merely want a random key, you should do something like this:

```
enc -aes-256-cbc -pass file:/dev/urandom -P
```

Btw, when you use `-p`/`-P`, apart from a `key` (and a `salt`), you'll also see an `iv`, which stands for [initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector).